# Bracket not expected in else statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, brackets

I have an error, unexpected brackets on an else statement, which makes no sense. What am I doing wrong?

```
if ($sortBy == "random") {
$sortByOption1 = "selected";
} 
else if ($sortBy == "mostvotes") {
$sortByOption2 = "selected";
} 
else ($sortBy == "newest") {
$sortByOption3 = "selected";
}
```

**Error:**

```
syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 9
```

Comment: `else` can't have a condition to enter it

Comment: `else {}` No statements with else.

Comment: Also to give an explanation why PHP complains about the `{` and not `(` is because there is no statement between the `else` and `{`. Theoretically you could have done something like this: `else $sortBy = "newest"; {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last part of your statement to this

```
else {
    $sortByOption3 = "selected";
}
```

Or if you don't want a default value set then change your 'else' to an 'else if'

```
elseif($sortBy == "newest") {
    $sortByOption3 = "selected";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either change `else ($sortBy == "newest")` to `else if ($sortBy == "newest")` or just  `else`. If you are putting a condition it has to be an `else if` not a plain `else`.